# PHP Script Runs out of memory

Tags: php

My PHP code is supposed to generate 1000 random words with a random length between 3 and 7 chars. And then it is supposed to compare each word to all the words in my dictionary, engmix.txt, and place the matches into an array and all the nonmatches into another array. I know the code functions correctly, but it runs out of memory on both computers that I have tried running it on. I am using XAMPP as my webserver and even tested removing the memory limit to see if it would run. I would like advice on how to optimize this code.

```
<?php

ini_set('memory_limit', '-1');

function getRandomWord($len = 10) {
    $word = range('a', 'z');
    shuffle($word);
    return substr(implode($word), 0, $len);
}

$words = array();

for ($i = 0; $i < 300; $i++) {
    $words[$i] = getRandomWord(rand(3, 7));
}

$matches = array();
$nonmatches = array();

$k = 0;

$dictionary = file("engmix.txt");

for ($i=0; $i < count($dictionary); $i++) { 
        for ($j = 0; $j < count($words); $j++) {
            if ($dictionary[$i] == $words[$j]) {
                $matches[$k] = $words[$j];
                $k++;
            } else {
                $nonmatches[$k] = $words[$j];
                $k++;
            }
        }
     }

?>
```

New fixed code:

```
<?php

function getRandomWord($len = 10) {
    $word = range('a', 'z');
    shuffle($word);
    return substr(implode($word), 0, $len);
}

$words = array();

for ($i = 0; $i < 300; $i++) {
    $words[$i] = getRandomWord(rand(3, 7));
}

$matches = array();
$nonmatches = array();

$file = file("engmix.txt");

$i = 0;

$file_handle = fopen("engmix.txt", "r");

while (!feof($file_handle)) {
    $line = fgets($file_handle);
    $line = str_replace("\n", "", $line);
    $line = str_replace("\r", "", $line);

    for ($i = 0; $i < count($words); $i++) {
        if ($line == $words[$i]) {
            $matches[] = $words[$i];
        }
    }
}

fclose($file_handle);

$nonmatches = array_diff($words, $file);


print("<pre>");
print_r($matches);
print("<pre>");

print("<pre>");
print_r($nonmatches);
print("<pre>");

?>
```

Comment: You may need to see if you're in an infinite loop, or if the arrays are getting too large. Try echoing out a count of $matches and $nonmatches to see how large they grow.

Comment: Just how many words are there in that dictionary file of yours? Loading it all into an in-memory array could be memory-expensive

Comment: @MarkBaker There are 84074 words in the dictionary. What would be a less memory expensive way to load the file?

Comment: @aynber $matches and $nonmatches would be restricted by the 1000 words, so either could be from 0 to 1000 in size.

Comment: Are you sure? It looks like it would be 1000 * 84074, since it's within two loops.

Comment: Arrays use  lot of memory. A slower approach, but one that uses a lot less memory would be to iterate through the dictionary file checking against each word, rather than loading it all into memory

Comment: @aynber I just echo'd $matches and $nonmatches and you are correct. They are growing exponentially.

Comment: I have narrowed down the problem to the inner for and if loops. I have changed my loop to iterate through the dictionary file so there is no array for the dictionary anymore.

Comment: I have fixed my code. Thank you everyone for the help!